# how can i give type in getServerSideProps of Nextjs with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using NextJs + TypeScript to make a little clone project, but I got a problem with type in `getServerSideProps`.
As you can see, in `getServerSideProps`, I am fetching data using with `context.query`.
But some error message is not fixed and I don't understand why that error appears.

The error message is this.

[image]

```
Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
const genre: string | string[] | undefined
```

How can I fix this type problem?

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import Nav from "../components/Nav/Nav";

import Header from "../components/Header/Header";
import Results from "../components/Results/Results";
import requests from "../utils/requests";

import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

type HomeProps = {
  results: {}[];
};

export default function Home({ results }: HomeProps) {
  console.log(results);

  return (
    <div>
      <Results results={results} />
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const genre = context.query.genre 

  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3${
      requests[genre]?.url {/*this is problem line*/}  
   || requests.fetchTopRated.url
    }`
  );

  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    props: { results: data.results },
  };
};
```

Comment: You should narrow down `genre` type before using it to index the `requests` object, i.e. make sure `genre` is a string before calling `requests[genre]`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use like this;

```
type PageProps = {
  isAuthanticated: boolean,
  categories?: CategoryType[]
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<PageProps> = async (context) => {
  const _props: PageProps = {
    isAuthanticated: auth,
    categories: data.results
  }
  return { props: _props }
};

const Category: NextPage<PageProps> = (props) => {
  return(
    ...
  )
};
```

Comment: To extend on this, you can also type the dynamic route's slug using `export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<PageProps, {mySlug: string}> = async (context) => {}`

Answer (score 1):

When you receive params via context, the value could be either `string` or `string[]` (or undefined) so you need to cast. It could be a single genre or multiple genres in the URL.

`?genre=film` or `?genre=film&genre=music`

For you case, simply cast as string:

```
const genre = context.query.genre as string;
```

**UPDATE**

As per your comments, the first issue that you raised in the question was actually about casting to `string` as above.

The second issue, which you should not actually be seeing and must be a TS or module config issue, is related to trying to accessing a key as string by index on your vanilla object exported from `"../utils/requests";`

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ fetchTrending: { title: string; url: string; }; ...
```

Your data object has literal key names:

```
// ../utils/requests
export default { 
   fetchTrending: { 
      title: "Trending", 
      url: /trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US, 
   }, 
   fetchTopRated: { 
      title: "Top Rated", 
      url: /movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US, 
   }, 
};
```

Rather define the type like this:

```
export interface IRequest {
  [name: string]: {
    title: string;
    url: string;
  };
}

const data: IRequest = {
  fetchTrending: {
    title: "Trending",
    url: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US1`
  },
  fetchTopRated: {
    title: "Top Rated",
    url: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`
  }
};

export default data;
```

or you could use a Record to have strongly typed keys:

```
type RequestNames = "fetchTrending" | "fetchTopRated";

export const records: Record<
  RequestNames,
  {
    title: string;
    url: string;
  }
> = {
  fetchTrending: {
    title: "Trending",
    url: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US1`
  },
  fetchTopRated: {
    title: "Top Rated",
    url: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`
  }
};
```

Comment: i've already tested it. but, it's not fixed 
and error red line expand  "requests[genre]", not just "genre"

Comment: what error are you getting now? The error you originally received was due to the problem stated above.

Comment: error message is this .
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ fetchTrending: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchTopRated: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchActionMovies: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchComedyMovies: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchHorrorMovies: { ...; }; ... 5 more ...; fetchTV: { ...; }; }'.

Comment: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ fetchTrending: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchTopRated: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchActionMovies: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchComedyMovies: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchHorrorMovies: { ...; }; ... 5 more ...; fetchTV: { ...; }; }'.

Comment: ok, you are trying to index an object it seems. `import requests from "../utils/requests"` doesn't seem to be exporting an array? what data is being exported there?

Comment: exported data structure is this

const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

export default {
  fetchTrending: {
    title: "Trending",
    url: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
  },
  fetchTopRated: {
    title: "Top Rated",
    url: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
  },
};

Comment: if i cast string type, error message is that 
'' Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ fetchTrending: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchTopRated: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchActionMovies: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchComedyMovies: { title: string; url: string; }; fetchHorrorMovies: { ...; }; ... 5 more ...; fetchTV: { ...; }; }'.''

Comment: hey samuel!, i solve this problem!
this reasons is that  i didn't think about index signature. when i was export requests, i need to give a index signature i requests like "type RequestsType = {
  [fetchType: string]: {
    title: string;
    url: string;
  };
};" !!
thank you so much for think with me this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of `genre` can be `string` *or* `string[]` (or undefined), it can not be used to index `requests` without being narrowed down to `string` via the use of an `if` statement:

```js
if (typeof genre === 'string') {
  // Typescript now knows it is a string
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3${
      requests[genre]?.fetchTopRated.url {/*this is problem line*/}  
   || requests.fetchTopRated.url
    }`
  );

  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    props: { results: data.results },
  };
} else if (typeof genre == 'object'){
   // handle case where it is an array
} else {
  // genre is undefined
}
```